# Looking for PostgreSQL or MySQL LogAppender

Tags: postgresql, kaa

Has anyone point me to a PostgreSQL log appender for kaa? Thanks a lot!

James

Comment: i'll try again. I am using kaa 0.10.0 on ubuntu 14, and would like to know whether anyone has developed a PostgreSQL log appender that can be shared. I did google the topic but was not able to find anything. I'd appreciate if someone can point out how I should ask the question or where I may find an answer. thanks

Answer (score 1):

We had a requirement similar to this. We wrote a custom JDBC log appender which was very customized for our needs and requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a guide to [creating custom log appender](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Customization-guide/Customizable-system-components/Log-appenders/) in documentation. Also here is the [code examples](https://github.com/kaaproject/kaa/tree/master/server/appenders) of log appenders available in Kaa by default.

Answer (score 0):

I used Django and postgres on AWS and created a rest API within the django app. Was quite easy to set it up. You can reference the procedure [here](http://agiliq.com/blog/2014/12/building-a-restful-api-with-django-rest-framework/). It all worked fine with the already built-in REST log appender in the kaa sandbox.