# Which framework best to use for a cross-platform cross-devices platform with multiple apps

Tags: android, ios, database, windows, cross-platform

I am working out an idea for some applications.
The applications needs to run on:

---

- Windows as a desktop / UWP app
- Android as a mobile app
- IOS as a mobile app
- Windows Phone as a mobile app
- Website as a web application

---

All applications will have the same functions.
All applications will need to view, edit and store information in and from a database.

I used to program in VB back in the days that we only had windows forms and I am new to the nowadays frameworks.

Till now I was thinking about creating a webservice to let all applications communicate with the database and then create all the other applications in their own framework / languages.
I have found some articles about ASP.NET WebAPI which looked like what I needed for the webservice but I don't know if I can also use that for Android and IOS. 
I also found something about Xamarin for building apps for all the platforms I am targeting.

Could anyone maybe inform me what framework best to use in this case.

Should I use Xamarin for the client apps? or is it better to create the apps in their own framework per platform?

Should I make the webservice with ASP.NET WebAPI? or is there an other framework which will be better in this case?

I also found something about Node.JS but am not sure what its for.

I am asking this because I need to educate myself in the languages / frameworks before I can start programming and I don't want to start educating in everything and in the end find out that it is useless in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I´m using Kaa Platform(https://www.kaaproject.org/) to manage all comunication between devices ( ios, android, WP, etc ). 
And for developing, i strongly recomend:

- if you will use just android and ios: react-native ( https://facebook.github.io/react-native/)
- if you will use android, ios and others: ionic ( https://ionicframework.com/)

Comment: I have a MySQL database which stores information that the apps need to view, edit and store. Is it possible with the Kaa platform to give the IOS, Android and Windows apps access to such database? For what I have seen on the website it's more an IOT thing for sensor data collection. My applications need to handle cooking recipes, groceries list etc.

Comment: Yes, the Kaa platform is more an IOT thing, but i guess your application is an IOT, right? Because you need the same app running on differents platforms.
 In Kaa, you can use your MySQL database, i can´t tell you exactly how, but i know it´s possible. I recomend this readings:

1- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42312342/looking-for-postgresql-or-mysql-logappender

2 - http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/MariaDB+cluster+installation